Question regarding intersection of two graphs
Suppose we have two simple, connected, undirected graphs $G_1 = (V(G_1),E(G_1))$ and $G_2 = (V(G_2),E(G_2))$.
Now from book of Diestel (Graph Theory), intersection of two graph is nothing but,
\begin{align}
G_1\cap G_2 = ((V(G_1) \cap V(G_2)), E(G_1)\cap E(G_2)).
\end{align}
My question out of curiosity, is the following,
Suppose, $G_1$ is isomorphic to $G_2$, and $|V(G_1)| = |V(G_2)| = N$ and $|E(G_1)| = |E(G_2)| = M$ and suppose $|V(G_1)\cap V(G_2)| = r$.

Then what can we say about the $|E(G_1)\cap E(G_2)|$ in terms of $N$, $M$ and $r$?
Is there any non-trivial lower bound over $|E(G_1)\cap E(G_2)|$ available in the literature?

As a example, if $G_1$ and $G_2$ is a complete graph with $N$ vertices, then $|E(G_1)\cap E(G_2)| = r(r-1)/2$. Since intersection of two isomorphic complete graph again a complete graph.
Similarly, if $G_1$ and $G_2$ is an $(N-1)$-star graph then,
$|E(G_1)\cap E(G_2)| = r-1$.
Can we generalise this result for general graph $G_1$ and $G_2$?

For the intersection of star graphs, you seem to be assuming that the central vertex is part of both $G_1$ and $G_2$. There's no reason this has to be the case - you could have two isomorphic stars that share all of their outer vertices but not the central one, and then $|E(G_1) \cap E(G_2)| = 0$.
More generally, if $r \leq \alpha(G_1)$, then you certainly could have $|E(G_1) \cap E(G_2)| = 0$ by making two copies of $G_1$ agree only on an independent set.

yes, you’r right

Foreword. This answer is coming from somebody who has only taken a single course in Graph Theory. And so while the answer to your question does seem elementary enough for somebody of my "skill-level" to provide a satisfactory response, those who are actively participating in the field may be able to provide more enlightening information. In any case, however, I hope this response comes across as helpful.

What can we say about the $|(_1)∩(_2)|$ in terms of $$, $$ and $?$ Not very much interesting, as far as I see it. Consider any complete graph $K_{n}$, and take any two triangle subgraphs. These graphs will be isomorphic, though the number of edges they share could be anywhere from $0$ to $3$. (An easy example which demonstrates this would be $K_{9}$. For a less trivial example, consider $K_4$.) This sort of idea generalizes to arbitrary graphs, not just triangles.
It may be of interest, however, to classify all graphs up to how many of a particular subgraph they have up to isomorphism. See Kuratowski's Theorem, see how trees denote graphs which contain no cyclic subgraphs, etc etc.
Is there any non-trivial lower bound over $|(_1)∩(_2)|$ available in the literature? The question as it is structure for the moment can be answer by referencing my response to your previous question: It is possible for isomorphic graphs to share no edges, just as it is possible for them to share all edges.
Though maybe somebody could derive some interesting characterizations of graphs according to how the intersection of isomorphic graphs behave. An elementary observation would be how all subgraphs isomorphic to a triangle in $K_4$ must share at least one edge. Something a slight bit more complicated could revolve around how a graph will be 2-connected if and only if all pairs of vertices share at least one cyclic subgraph.
